# how to set iphone tab bar icon by custom images using story board

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.5, uitabbar

I am newbie to iphone development,I need to put a custom image icon in the tab bar .But it showing only the default colour(Black&blue) .Help me to overcome from this bug friends...?

Comment: try it in coding UIImage

Answer (score 23, accepted):

add the Images in application,

and See attached Image

[image]

Comment: the selected images are not wokring.. i tried from the identify inspector and attributes inspector xcode >6.1

Answer (score 6):

Use this code in viewDidLoad

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];

UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
```

Comment: Where do you get `tabBar` variable from ?

Comment: This method is deprecated now.

Comment: @SalehMasum Thank to draw my attention on that. If you know solution please edit my answer. I will accept that.

Answer (score 4):

**Use below code in AppDelegate**

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary  *)launchOptions
{


UIViewController *viewController1 = [[ViewFirstViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[ViewSecondViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewController3 = [[ViewThirdViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewController4 = [[ViewFourthViewController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


imgTab = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320.0,50)];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tag=10;
[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:imgTab];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

imghome=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,00.0,80.0,50.0)];
imghome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dressup_active.png"];
[imgTab addSubview:imghome];

imgQuiz=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0,00.0,81.0,50.0)];
imgQuiz.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"x-mas_tree.png"];
[imgTab addSubview:imgQuiz];

imgtTW=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(161.0,00.0,80.0,50.0)];
imgtTW.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greetings.png"];
[imgTab addSubview:imgtTW];

imgGuest=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(241.0,00.0,80.0,50.0)];
imgGuest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"quotes_tab.png"];
[imgTab addSubview:imgGuest];

}
```

**Tabbar Controller delegate method**

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllers didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

NSLog(@"%i",tabBarControllers.selectedIndex);
if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 0)
{

    imghome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dressup_active.png"];
    imgQuiz.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"x-mas_tree.png"];
    imgtTW.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greetings.png"];
    imgGuest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"quotes_tab.png"];

}
else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 1)
{

    imghome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dressup.png"];
    imgQuiz.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"x-mas_tree_active.png"];
    imgtTW.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greetings.png"];
    imgGuest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"quotes_tab.png"];

}
else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 2)
{

    imghome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dressup.png"];
    imgQuiz.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"x-mas_tree.png"];
    imgtTW.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greetings_active.png"];
    imgGuest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"quotes_tab.png"];

}
else if (tabBarControllers.selectedIndex == 3)
{

    imghome.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dressup.png"];
    imgQuiz.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"x-mas_tree.png"];
    imgtTW.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"greetings.png"];
    imgGuest.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"quotes_active.png"];

}



}
```

Comment: thank you so much dude i was searching exactly for this thanks a lot +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code snippet for ios7:

```
UIImage *iconBoxOffice = [UIImage imageNamed:@"box-office.png"];
UIImage *selectedIconBoxOffice = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-box-office.png"];
UIImage *iconDvds = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dvds.png"];
UIImage *selectedIconDvds = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dvds.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

[item0 initWithTitle:@"Box Office" image:iconBoxOffice selectedImage:selectedIconBoxOffice];
[item1 initWithTitle:@"Dvds" image:iconDvds selectedImage:selectedIconDvds];
```

You can keep adding more items if you have more tabs.
*don't forget to add the images to your project
*this is done programmatically, not using storyboards

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a custom image (icon and background) to the tab bar and not just change the blue icon:

Add the code below to your first UIView .m-file. 
If you start fresh with a "Tabbed Application" project it's called FirstViewController.m
Don't forget to add the images (and set check mark 'Copy items into destination group's folder') to your project and choose better names for the images.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customIcon0_unpressed.png"];
  UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customIcon0_unpressed.png"];

  UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customIcon1_unpressed.png"];
  UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customIcon1_unpressed.png"];

  UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
  UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
  UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

  [item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
  [item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
}
```

You can find more informations about this solution and tons of other great tutorials on [Ray Wenderlichs](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) page.